# Moving values up in nested hierarchy until key is no longer named '_ignore'

Tags: javascript

Given an object as shown below, how would I approach moving all values up in the hierarchy until their parent no longer is named _ignore?

In an attempt to transform Excel CSV data to a nested object, I ended up with something that looks like the following:

```
// Old structure:
var obj = {
    _root: {},
    _top1: {
        "_ignore": {
            "_ignore": [
                "I can no longer traverse down",
                "so the list that contains this",
                "text should be placed under the",
                "_top1 node, which is the first",
                "parent not named _ignore. It should",
                "be the only child to '_top1'."
            ]
        } 
    },
    
    _top2: {}
}
```

_root and _top2 should not be touched, but the top1 should have the lowest-level list as its value in the final structure. I'd like the object to look like this:

```
// Desired structure:
var obj = {
    _root: {},
    _top1: [
            "I can no longer traverse down",
            "so the list that contains this",
            "text should be placed under the",
            "_top1 node, which is the first",
            "parent not named _ignore"
            ], 
    
    _top2: {}
}
```

I know I'm in the recursive domain, just haven't been able to apply it in a proper manner.
Help/direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you basically just want the contents of the deepest *_ignore*. Since you're also converting all ancestor objects (except for *obj* itself) to arrays, it's safe to say that any other properties can be destroyed. In other words, an object has either an *_ignore* property or is the actual content we're looking for.

In one sentence you could say; give me the contents of *_ignore* if is there, and recurse that.

In pseudo code:

```
function findContents (level) {
    if (i have an ignored level)
        return findContents (ignored level)
    else
        return level
}
```

In Javascript code:

```
const findContents = obj => obj._ignore
    ? findContents(obj._ignore)
    : obj;
```

And to apply that to your structure:

```
obj._top1 = findContents(obj._top1);
```

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this function can help you:

```
const removeIgnore = (obj) => {

    let newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);

    const findStructure = (obj) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(obj)
        if (keys.length == 0) return obj
        return (keys[0] === '_ignore') ? findStructure(obj[keys[0]]) : obj
    }

    for (k in newObj) newObj[k] = findStructure(newObj[k])

    return newObj
}
```

It will iterate over all root keys, and search for the deepest structure that is not part of a `_ignore` key. Will return a **new** object with the modified data.

Demo:

```
/* 3 deeps _ignore */
var obj = {
    _root: {},
    _top1: {
        "_ignore": {
            "_ignore": {
                "_ignore": [
                    "I can no longer traverse down",
                    "so the list that contains this",
                    "text should be placed under the",
                    "_top1 node, which is the first",
                    "parent not named _ignore. It should",
                    "be the only child to '_top1'."
                ]
            }
        } 
    },

    _top2: {}
}


const newObj = removeIgnore(obj);

console.log(newObj);

/*
{ _root: {},
  _top1: 
   [ 'I can no longer traverse down',
     'so the list that contains this',
     'text should be placed under the',
     '_top1 node, which is the first',
     'parent not named _ignore. It should',
     'be the only child to \'_top1\'.' ],
  _top2: {} }

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a depth first search down the tree to replace the ignores

```js
var obj = {
    _root: {},
    _top1: {
        "_ignore": {
            "_ignore": [
                "I can no longer traverse down",
                "so the list that contains this",
                "text should be placed under the",
                "_top1 node, which is the first",
                "parent not named _ignore. It should",
                "be the only child to '_top1'."
            ]
        } 
    },

    _top2: {}
}
function hoistIgnore(item, parent, parent_key){
  if(Array.isArray(item) || !(typeof item === "object")) {
    parent[parent_key] = item;
    return item
  }
  for(var key in item){
    if(key === "_ignore"){
      hoistIgnore(item[key], parent, parent_key);
    } else {
      hoistIgnore(item[key], item, key);
    }
  }
  return item
}

console.log(hoistIgnore(obj))
```